# table needs to be fixed during scrolling with clicking on a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some problem with my scrolling.
I have 3 tables and one of them I want to be fix after scroll more then specific distance

```
var $table = $("#thead"),
$window = $(window),
distance = $table.offset().top;
text=$("div.text2"),
textdistance=text.offset().top;

$window.scroll(function () {
var wdistance = $window.scrollTop();

 if (wdistance > distance) {
    if( wdistance < textdistance )
    {table.addClass('fixed');}
    else {
    table.removeClass('fixed');
    }
  }else{
    table.removeClass('fixed'); 
 }
```

});

this is my first demo **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkafiyan/HmFW7/6/)**

I want to say when this "if" is correct then position of div with "thead" id become fixed on top of the other tables when scrolling the page. and after the div with id "first" is finish then `<div id="thead"></div>` come back to previous place. 
and also another problem after clicking on more details because of the css that div with "more-detail" id get  `display:block, display:none,` ,the table with id "thead" scrolling both when clicking on more details or not.

this is my second demo **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mkafiyan/HmFW7/7/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct it **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HmFW7/11/)**

with height()

```
textdistance=distance + $tableBody.height();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using *$variablename* use the `$` symbol always while using the varaible.In your code you specified variable `var $table` and later used it simply as `table` without `$`.

## Fixed fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/HmFW7/8/

---

## Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/HmFW7/9/

Comment: tnx u fix one of my problems , dont'u have any idea about my another problem?

Comment: Pls clarify them.I am not getting the other problems

Comment: after finish the div with id "first" I want to table with fixed position come back to previous place.

Comment: Ok @mimi .Wait for my reply

Comment: I solved the problems but this way make another problem [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mkafiyan/HmFW7/10/) when clicking on more details   position of the table with id "thead" is still fixed .

Comment: Ok go on and accept your answer or mine just to show this question is answered